# Where can I find documentation on uv_poll_init?

Tags: libuv

I'm looking at a libuv example at https://github.com/benfleis/samples/blob/master/libuv/stdio/stdio_poll.c and trying to understand it.

I mostly understand it, but I'm having some trouble with the uv_poll_init's at the bottom, and I can't find any documentation.

Can someone point me to some documentation on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation is in the form of comments in the [`include/uv.h`](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/include/uv.h) header file, which provides the following documentation for [`uv_poll_init()`](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/652d5c9e4532fc01c8eebed5303eaf27618b963b/include/uv.h#L1140):

> Initialize the poll watcher using a file descriptor.

However, some better documentation that covers the concept of watchers, can be found [here](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/basics.html#watchers).  In short:

```c
uv_poll_init(loop, &stdin_watcher, STDIN_FILENO);
```

Initializes `stdin_watcher` to observe `STDIN_FILENO`.  When the watcher is started, all of its callbacks will be invoked within the context of `loop`.

Here is a basic pseudo-flow of the program:

```
stdout_cb:
  write whatever is in log_buf to stdout
  stop listening for when I can write to stdout

log:
  write message to log_buf
  have stdout_watcher listen for when its file becomes writeable
    when it becomes writable, stdout_cb will be called

stdint_cb:
  read from stdin
  call log

set_non_blocking:
  set file descriptor as non-blocking

main:
  set stdin/out to nonblocking

  get handle to default event loop
  initialize stdint_watcher, it will listen to stdin and its callback will
    run within the default loop
  initialize stdout_watcher, it will listen to stdout and its callback will
    run within the default loop
  have stdin_watcher listen for when its file becomes readable
    when it becomes readable, stdin_cb will be called
  run the event loop until no more work exists
    in this case, when both watchers are not running (i.e. stopped)
```

Answer (score 2):

Newest and latest and greatest documentation: http://docs.libuv.org/en/latest/